# How to give my mailid in my code itself for sending mail

Tags: android, android-intent

This is my code and i need to send mail!! Everything is working fine but i need my mailid to be given by default in the "to" field itself..instead getting from the user? Iam new to android plz help!!

```
      package com.example.newactivity;
      import android.app.Activity;
      import android.content.Intent;
      import android.os.Bundle;

       public class Revert extends Activity {
     String anu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String message = "Our Valuable Feedback";

    Intent emailintent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailintent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
            "xxx@gmail.com");

    emailintent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "i hate u");
    emailintent.setType("plain/text");
    emailintent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, message);
    startActivity(emailintent);
}
```

}

Comment: what do you mean by this statement .... my mailid to be given by default in the "to" field itself ??

Comment: I dont want the user to enter his mail id! i need the user to send it to me only!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to add recipient mail in the intent to send mail

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
```

body of mail

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
```

Comment: Instead of {"recipient@example.com"} im supposed to give my mail id ?

Comment: just give your mail id instead of "recipient@example.com" in code. it will send mail to that mail

Comment: Fine!! similarly can u tel me how to add contents in the body plz?

Comment: welcome.. remove your mail_id in the question ..just make it as  dummy mail id .. don't share your personal id's like this :)